# Is the splitting field of $x^3+2x^2-x-3$ a totally ramified extension of $\mathbb Q_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+2x^2-x-3 \in \mathbb Q_5[x]$.

> Is the field $K:=\mathbb Q_5[x]/(f(x))$ totally ramified ?

Through Newton polygon argument, I see $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q_5$. (Is there other way to check irreducibility of this polynomial ?)

Therefore $K=\mathbb Q_5(\theta)$ for some root $\theta$ of $f(x)$.

We compute the value groups $G_1$ and $G_2$  of $\mathbb Q_5$ and $\mathbb Q_5(\theta)$ respectively.
\begin{align}
&G_1=\{5^m~:~m \in \mathbb Z\} \\
&G_2=\{5^{\frac{m}{3}}:~m \in \mathbb Z\},~\text{since degree of extension is 3}
\end{align}

Therefore the index $[G_2:G_1]=[5^{\mathbb Z}:5^{3 \mathbb Z}]=3$, which would be the ramification index $e=3$. Therefore totally ramified extension.

Am I doing correct or missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there other way to check irreducibility of this polynomial?

Yes: it is irreducible mod $5$ (since it has no root mod $5$ and is cubic), so it is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_5$.  Because this polynomial mod $5$ is irreducible, its splitting field over $\mathbf Q_5$ is *unramified* of degree $3$.

The reasoning (that you don't provide) behind your calculation of $G_2 = |K^\times|_5$ is incorrect: just because the formula for the $5$-adic absolute value on $K$ involves taking a cube root, that doesn't make $|K^\times|_5 = 5^{(1/3)\mathbf Z}$: norms from $K$ down to $\mathbf Q_5$ could all have (and in fact *do* have) $5$-adic valuation divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the 2nd line of 1st para ? Why is it unramified ? Is it because every irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$ will have roots in $\mathbb F_{p^{\text{deg}(f)}}$ and so $f=[\mathbb F_{p^{\text{deg}(f)}}: \mathbb F_p]=n$, in this case $n=3$ ? Is this the reason

Comment: If $f(x) \bmod p$ is irreducible  then adjoining one root of $f(x)$  to $\mathbf Q_p$ gives you its splitting field over $\mathbf Q_p$ (similar to the behavior of irreducibles over $\mathbf F_p$) and it is unramified. For more details, read about unramified extensions in books on $p$-adic analysis or local fields.

Comment: Suppose $g(x)$ is an Eisenstein polynomial over $\mathbb Q_p$, then also adjoining one root of $g(x)$ to $\mathbb Q_p$ would give us the splitting field of $g(x)$ and it would be totally ramified. Also since $g(x)$ is Eisenstein, mod $p$ will also be irreducible. So it also satisfies your last comment though it is totally ramified. So I am not getting something here.

Comment: Your comment is incorrect. An Eisenstein polynomial at $p$ of degree bigger than $1$ is never irreducible mod $p$. And  adjoining to $\mathbf Q_p$ one root of an Eisenstein polynomial at $p$ need not give its splitting field: try the simplest example $x^p - p$ when $p \not= 2$. Did you look at any examples with degree bigger than $2$ besides the cyclotomic extensions $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_{p^r})$?

Comment: It is true that adjoining to $\mathbf Q_p$ a root of an Eisenstein polynomial at $p$ gives a totally ramified extension. But the other things you had written are incorrect (sometimes).

Comment: I need little bit more help. In my above example, we have $[\mathbb Q_p(\alpha): \mathbb Q_p]=\deg f=3=[\mathbb F_p^{\deg f}: \mathbb F]$, so the inertial degree is $3$ and hence unramified. Do you mean that ? Finally one question, Do always we have $[\mathbb Q_p(\alpha) : \mathbb Q_p]=\deg (f)$ where $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\alpha$ is its root ? Thanks

Comment: I advise you to speak with a professor or classmate about these issues.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, I have no such option. There are no other studying number theory here in my university. Often I get confused with unramified extension. For totally ramified case it is clear that we have an Eisenstein polynomial. I always get stick the formula $n=ef=[L:K] \cdot [l: \kappa]$, where $[L;K]<\infty$ and $l, \kappa$ are respective residue field. In my above example, $n=3$ and $f=3$, therefore $e$=ramification-index=$1$. Therefore unramified. So everytime we have to compute $e$ to get a conclusion. This is my understanding that $e$ is not directly available.

Comment: The formula $ef = [L:K][l:\kappa]$ is incorrect since $n=[L:K]$. You say $e$ is not “directly available”, but neither is $f$. Depending on how the extension is described, neither $e$ nor $f$ may be immediately accessible.  In any case, a recognition theorem for unramified extensions (analogous to adjoining the root of an Eisenstein polynomial for recognizing totally ramified extensions) is that $L/K$ is unramified if $L= K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the root of a monic polynomial in $\mathcal O_K[x]$ that reduces to a separable polynomial (not necessarily irreducible) in $\kappa[x]$.

Comment: Sorry I again wrote wrong. I meant to say $[L: K]=e \cdot [l: \kappa]$. Thank you for your explanation.